# Is it possible to specify that argument passed to a jit function will be numba dict type or must it be assumed?

Tags: python, numba

I'm looking to get marginal performance gains out of a simulation I'm running. Is the following possible.

I want something like:

```
@njit('int64(DictType[int64,int64], int64)')
def func(d, el):
    return d[el]
```

I just want to specify that 'd', the input to a function will be a numba dict.

Comment: How would specifying the type help with performance?

Comment: Nothing about that in numba's own python performance tips (and also, `njit` wouldn't except such arguments): https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html

Comment: I've found compilation time is significantly reduced if argument types are specified